# Books on custom iPhone interface development?

Tags: books, ios, user-interface

I have been looking around for a book on designing and developing custom interfaces for iOS but I don't seem to be able to find any books on this topic and I was wondering if anyone here knew of any books on the design and development of custom iOS interfaces and applications.

Also, I am not aware of any other questions asked on this site, so if there is, please do let me know and I'll vote to delete :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "custom interface"?
Do you mean interfaces that don't look being built using Cocoa Touch native widgets? If yes then don't estimate the power of Cocoa Touch and graphics.
UITableView for example is a versatile widget, you can't believe how much you achieve with it.

With Quartz 2D, Core Animation and graphics you can achieve extremely lovely interfaces.

[iOS Recipes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1934356743) contains a lot of tricks and tips that will help you customizing your interfaces. Check the book's TOC.

Comment: I do indeed mean interfaces that do not look like the native UI elements. For example, instead of having a UITableView look like a normal table view, have a notepad as the background.

Comment: I told you, this where graphics come in handy.

Comment: Yea, I've actually just purchased that book your recommended from Amazon! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of any books off the top of my head, but the custom interface designs are mostly done using Core Graphics, so that should give you a good starting point. There is of course [an O'Reilly](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449305679) .